# How to refresh(reload) current url in Rails Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a test using Minitest in rails, **i need to refresh the page(url) without get request** so that i can see ajax changes made on page

```
  test "z" do
    assert_select "my_div", 0
    ajax_activity()
    #here i want to refresh the page
    # right now i am using get "/dashboard"
    #which is working fine
    get "/dashboard"
    assert_select "my_div", "1"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and some headless [browser driver](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver) (e.g. selenium) to be able to test ajax activity (or javascript in general) on your pages. Be sure to read the [README chapter](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends) dealing with AJAX requests and timeouts too.

Some introductory guidance can be taken from [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara) (though it uses RSpec instead of Minitest), there is a plenty of [more](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/capybara-minitest-rails/) [concrete](http://www.jevon.org/wiki/Using_Capybara_with_Minitest_for_Integration_Tests_in_Rails_4) information on the web, try googling for something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20capybara%20testing#hl=cs&q=rails%20capybara%20minitest%20testing). Be sure to read the capybara [README chapter](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends) dealing with AJAX requests and timeouts too.

Answer (score 1):

[`page.refresh`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FSession:refresh) will do the trick!